# Dict nested to excel

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dict with these value :

```
{'Page': ['5', '3', '2'], 'PageSize': [1, 1, 1], 'SolvePage': [0, 0, 0], 'Subject': ['None', 'None', 'None'], 'QuestionsNumbers': ['0', '0', '0'], 'Comment': ['None', 'None', 'None'], 'Date': ['15:51:07', '15:51:04', '15:51:03'], 'TotalPages': [0, 0, 0, 3], 'TotalSolvesPages': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'TotalLeftPages': [0, 0, 0, 3]}]
```

and i want to add this dict to excel by each name of key get a table name and its value get the value of column and etc..
so in the end it should be look like this in excel :
[image]

please help me to get the code in python for create excel file from the this dict

what i use in the code :

```
import datetime
import os
import pandas as pd
  
df = {
    'Page': [],
    'PageSize': [],
    'SolvePage': [],
    'Subject': [],
    'QuestionsNumbers': [],
    'Comment': [],
    'Date': [],
    'TotalPages': [],
    'TotalSolvesPages': [],
    'TotalLeftPages': []
}
temp_da = {
    'Page': [],
    'PageSize': [],
    'SolvePage': [],
    'Subject': [],
    'QuestionsNumbers': [],
    'Comment': [],
    'Date': [],
    'TotalPages': [],
    'TotalSolvesPages': [],
    'TotalLeftPages': []
}

temp_index_in_page = []
df_temp = []
tempTotalPage = {0}
tempTotalSolvesPage = {0}
tempTotalLeftPage = {0}
answer_1 = True
answer_2 = True
Error_Mas = '    ERROR! You cannot enter Dot/Space/Empty value between page or in the page syntax:\n'\
                      '    1.If you want to enter more then one page:\n'\
                      '      Try to enter - between each page - for example 15-16.\n'\
                      '    2.If you want to enter single page:\n'\
                      '      Try to enter just the page number - for example 15'\
                      '    Reopen the program...'

def get_index_item(key, a_list):
    a_list = list(a_list)
    index = a_list.index(key)
    if not index:
        return 0
    else:
        return index

def get_last_item(a_list):
    if not a_list:
        return 0
    else:
        tempVar = len(a_list) + 1
        return tempVar
def get_last_item_v2(a_list):
    if not a_list:
        return 0
    else:
        tempVar = len(a_list)-1
        return tempVar

def get_highest_max_substrac_min(var):
    for each in var:
        if '-' in each:
            page1, page2 = each.split('-')
            page1 = int(page1)
            page2 = int(page2)
            if page1 > page2:
                Max_int = int(page1)
                Min_int = int(page2)
                calc = Max_int - Min_int
                if calc == 0:
                    calc = 1
                    return calc
                elif calc != 0:
                    return calc
                else:
                    return 1
            elif page1 < page2:
                Max_int = int(page2)
                Min_int = int(page1)
                calc = Max_int - Min_int
                if calc == 0:
                    calc = 1
                    return calc
                else:
                    return calc
            elif page1 == page2:
                return 1
        else:
            return 1

def get_sorted_numbers(key):
    if '-' in key:
        page1, page2 = key.split('-')
        Max = max(page1, page2)
        Min = min(page1, page2)
        Max_int = int(Max)
        Min_int = int(Min)
        to_min_and_max_value_sorted = f'{Min_int}-{Max_int}'
        return to_min_and_max_value_sorted
    else:
        return key

def total_TotalLeftPages():
    global tempTotalLeftPage
    tempCalc = []
    for T_P, T_SP in zip(df['TotalPages'], df['TotalSolvesPages']):
        T_P = int(T_P)
        T_SP = int(T_SP)
        calc = T_P - T_SP
        tempCalc.append(calc)
    last_item = int(get_last_item_v2(tempCalc))
    calc = tempCalc[last_item]
    if not df['TotalLeftPages']:
        df['TotalLeftPages'].insert(0,0)
        df['TotalLeftPages'].append(calc)
    else:
        df['TotalLeftPages'].clear()
        for num,each in enumerate(df['Page']):
            num = 0
            df['TotalLeftPages'].append(num)
        df['TotalLeftPages'].append(calc)

def total_TotalSolvesPages():
    global tempTotalSolvesPage
    tempSum = []
    for page in df['SolvePage']:
        page = int(page)
        if page == 0:
            page_int = 0
            tempTotalSolvesPage.add(page_int)
        else:
            page_int = int(page)
            tempTotalSolvesPage.add(page_int)
    Sum = sum(tempTotalSolvesPage)
    tempSum.append(Sum)
    Sum = sum(tempSum)
    if not df['TotalSolvesPages']:
        return df['TotalSolvesPages'].append(0),df['TotalSolvesPages'].append(Sum)
    elif df['TotalSolvesPages']:
        # df['TotalSolvesPages'].clear()
        return df['TotalSolvesPages'].append(Sum)
    tempTotalSolvesPage.clear()
    tempSum.clear()

def total_TotalPages():
    tempList = []
    for page in df['PageSize']:
        page = int(page)
        tempList.append(page)
    Sum = sum(tempList)

    if not df['TotalPages']:
        return df['TotalPages'].append(0),df['TotalPages'].append(Sum)
    elif df['TotalPages']:
        df['TotalPages'].clear()
        for num,each in enumerate(df['Page']):
            num = 0
            df['TotalPages'].append(num)
        return df['TotalPages'].append(Sum)

def chack_page_v1(inp_page):
    global df
    global df_temp
    if '-' in inp_page:
        page1, page2 = inp_page.split('-')
        Max = max(page1, page2)
        Min = min(page1, page2)
        Max_int = int(Max)
        Min_int = int(Min)
        to_min_and_max_value_sorted = f'{Min_int}-{Max_int}'
        if to_min_and_max_value_sorted in df['Page']:
            print(' The page you enter is already in the database, ignoring...')
        else:
            print(f' Adding page number : {inp_page} to database...')
            df['Page'].insert(get_last_item(df['Page']), to_min_and_max_value_sorted)
            df_temp.append(inp_page)
            df['Page'] = sorted(df['Page'], reverse=True)
    elif inp_page in df['Page']:
        print(' The page you enter is already in the database, ignoring...')
    else:
        print(f' Adding page number : {inp_page} to database...')
        df['Page'].append(inp_page)
        df['Page'] = sorted(df['Page'], reverse=True)
        df_temp.append(inp_page)

def page_size():
    global df
    global df_temp
    global temp_index_in_page
    var_1 = df_temp[0]
    try:
        if df_temp[0] in df['Page']:
            var = get_highest_max_substrac_min(df_temp)
            i = df['Page'].index(df_temp[0])
            df['PageSize'].insert(i, var)
            df['SolvePage'].insert(i, 0)
        else:
            if '-' in var_1:
                page_enter_sorted = get_sorted_numbers(var_1)
                for each in df['Page']:
                    if page_enter_sorted == each:
                        temp_list.append(df['Page'].index(each))
                index_page_enter = int(temp_list[0])
                var = get_highest_max_substrac_min(df_temp)
                df['PageSize'].insert(index_page_enter, var)
                df['SolvePage'].insert(index_page_enter, 0)
            else:
                last = get_last_item(df['PageSize'])
                var = get_highest_max_substrac_min(df_temp)
                df['PageSize'].insert(last, var)
                df['SolvePage'].append(0)
    except ValueError:
        print(Error_Mas)

def page_solve():
    for_while = True
    temp_list_num = []
    temp_list_page = []
    get_range_pages = []
    get_page_from_user = []
    get_range_pages_get_solve_page = []
    checkSumSolvePage = sum(df['SolvePage'])
    if not df['SolvePage']:
        print('Error! Cant solve page with non value , try to enter any page then enter the solve pages menu.')
    else:
        print('\nList of all the page number : ')
        for num_print, page_print in enumerate(df['Page']):
            print(f'  For picking page number {page_print} enter the key {num_print}')
            temp_list_num.append(num_print)
            temp_list_page.append(page_print)
        while for_while:
            answer = input('Enter here you choosing : ')
            try:
                if answer not in str(temp_list_num):
                    print(' ERROR! You enter not exist page pick , pick again')
                elif answer in str(temp_list_num):
                    if checkSumSolvePage == 0:
                        get_page_from_user.append(temp_list_page[int(answer)])
                        get_range_pages.append(df['PageSize'][int(answer)])
                    else:
                        get_page_from_user.append(temp_list_page[int(answer)])
                        get_range_pages.append(df['PageSize'][int(answer)])
                        get_range_pages_get_solve_page.append(df['SolvePage'][int(answer)])
                        value = int(get_range_pages[0]) - int(get_range_pages_get_solve_page[0])
                        get_range_pages.clear()
                        get_range_pages.append(value)

                    get_range_pages = get_range_pages[0]
                    get_page_from_user = get_page_from_user[0]
                    print('The pages', get_page_from_user)
                    print('The calc pages is', get_range_pages)
                    get_pages_substrac = input(f'How many pages did you finish in page {get_page_from_user}? ')
                    get_pages_substrac = int(get_pages_substrac)
                    if get_range_pages < get_pages_substrac:
                        print(
                            f'your input for finish in pages in more then the calc of the pages : the calc between the '
                            f'pages is : {get_range_pages}')
                    elif get_range_pages == get_pages_substrac:
                        if '-' in get_page_from_user:
                            var = df['SolvePage'][int(answer)]
                            df['SolvePage'].pop(int(answer))
                            new_var = var + get_pages_substrac
                            print(new_var)
                            df['SolvePage'].insert(int(answer), new_var)
                        else:
                            df['SolvePage'].pop(int(answer))
                            df['SolvePage'].insert(int(answer), 1)
                    else:
                        var = df['SolvePage'][int(answer)]
                        df['SolvePage'].pop(int(answer))
                        new_var = var + get_pages_substrac
                        df['SolvePage'].insert(int(answer), new_var)
                    for_while = False
            except ValueError:
                print('ERROR ! You enter the wrong key , try again')

a = 0
def save_new_excel_file(path):
    try:
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            global a
            global df
            global temp_da
            path_for_stand_along_excel = os.path.join(path, 'HomeWorkPage.xlsx')
            da = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df,orient='index')
            Try = True
            while Try:
                try:
                    if os.path.exists(path_for_stand_along_excel):
                        os.remove(path_for_stand_along_excel)
                        writeToExcel = pd.ExcelWriter(path_for_stand_along_excel)
                        da.to_excel(writeToExcel, index=False)
                        writeToExcel.save()
                        print('create new excel file')
                        Try = False
                    else:
                        writeToExcel = pd.ExcelWriter(path_for_stand_along_excel)
                        da.to_excel(writeToExcel, index=False)
                        writeToExcel.save()
                        print('create new excel file')
                        Try = False
                except PermissionError:
                    print('Data not attached to open excel , try reopen the program and run ')
                    answer = input('Re-try again ? (y/n)')
                    if answer == 'y':
                        pass
                    elif answer == 'n':
                        Try = False
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('seems like the path is not exsist in your PC , try to run again with the correct path')

while True:
    print('The syntax to insert pages is :\n'
          ' 1.If you want to enter more then one page:\n'
          '   Try to enter - between each page - for example 15-16.\n'
          ' 2.If you want to enter single page:\n'
          '   Try to enter just the page number - for example 15\n')
    print('---\n'
          'To Insert New HomeWork pages enter (1)\n'
          'To insert solution pages enter (2)\n'
          '---')
    temp_list = []

    while answer_1:
        main_answer = input('\nPlease Enter your answer here (1/2) : ')
        if main_answer == '1':
            try:
                page_enter = input(' Enter the page numbers please : ')
                if page_enter in df['Page'] or '.' in page_enter or page_enter == '':
                    print(Error_Mas)
                else:
                    chack_page_v1(str(page_enter))
                    page_size()
                    df_temp.clear()
                    temp_list.clear()
                    Now = datetime.datetime.now()
                    date_correct = Now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                    page_enter_sorted = get_sorted_numbers(page_enter)
                    for each in df['Page']:
                        if page_enter_sorted == each:
                            temp_list.append(df['Page'].index(each))
                    index_page_enter = int(temp_list[0])
                    df['Date'].insert(index_page_enter,date_correct)
                    subject_enter = input('  Enter your subject enter please : Default is == (None) ')
                    if subject_enter == '':
                        df['Subject'].insert(index_page_enter,'None')
                    else:
                        df['Subject'].append(subject_enter)
                    question = input(f'  Any specific question ? Default is == (None) ')
                    if question == '':
                        df['QuestionsNumbers'].insert(index_page_enter,'0')
                    else:
                        df['QuestionsNumbers'].insert(index_page_enter,question)
                    comment = input('  Any comment to this page ? Default is == (None)')
                    if comment == '':
                        df['Comment'].insert(index_page_enter,'None')
                    else:
                        df['Comment'].insert(index_page_enter,comment)
                    print(f'   **Page number {page_enter} successfully added to excel file**')
                    total_TotalPages()
                    total_TotalSolvesPages()
                    total_TotalLeftPages()
                    save_new_excel_file(r'D:\Try\New folder(3)')
                    print(df)

            except IndexError:
                print(Error_Mas)
        if main_answer == '2':
            page_solve()
            save_new_excel_file(r'D:\Try\New folder(3)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working dictionary comprehension with `Series` constructors, because some lists has different lengths:

```
d = {'Page': ['5', '3', '2'], 'PageSize': [1, 1, 1], 'SolvePage': [0, 0, 0], 'Subject': ['None', 'None', 'None'], 'QuestionsNumbers': ['0', '0', '0'], 'Comment': ['None', 'None', 'None'], 'Date': ['15:51:07', '15:51:04', '15:51:03'], 'TotalPages': [0, 0, 0, 3], 'TotalSolvesPages': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'TotalLeftPages': [0, 0, 0, 3]}

da = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in d.items()})
print (da)
  Page  PageSize  SolvePage Subject QuestionsNumbers Comment      Date  \
0    5       1.0        0.0    None                0    None  15:51:07   
1    3       1.0        0.0    None                0    None  15:51:04   
2    2       1.0        0.0    None                0    None  15:51:03   
3  NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN              NaN     NaN       NaN   

   TotalPages  TotalSolvesPages  TotalLeftPages  
0           0                 0               0  
1           0                 0               0  
2           0                 0               0  
3           3                 0               3  

df.to_excel(file, index=False)
```